# How do I limit inbound and outbound bandwidth to and from a specific host on CentOS

Tags: linux, networking, centos, network-interface, bandwidth

I am trying to limit inbound and outbound bandwidth to and from a specific host on CentOS. The reason is that this host consistently uses a large amount of bandwidth and this needs to be limited while other hosts needs to be able to connect freely without limitation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The match ip rule in tc is probably your best option.  A quick example for outbound:

```
  tc qdisc add dev $DEV root handle 1: cbq avpkt 1000 bandwidth 10mbit 

  tc class add dev $DEV parent 1: classid 1:1 cbq rate 512kbit \
  allot 1500 prio 5 bounded isolated 

  tc filter add dev $DEV parent 1: protocol ip prio 16 u32 \
  match ip dst $DESTINATION_IP flowid 1:1
```

You can also do `match ip src` for inbound.

Source: http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.ratelimit.single.html